# Unable to retrieve mongoose object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I cannot read the mongoose object property when debugging. Instead, setters and getters are available related to each property of the object.

Debugging example data retrieved

[image]

I am using node js (debugging via VSCode) and the system works perfectly when I am not debugging.

This is the .vscode launch.json configuration for debugging

[image]

Why I cannot see the value for each property of the model like a normal object?

Comment: That's because it's a mongoose document, if you want to get a javascript object you need to see the value of `document.toObject()`

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I was able to see the object before. I believe is some configuration of vs code

Comment: anyone found solution to this?